# Creating a mock data object for unit testing

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, codable

Currently I'm trying to unit test a function that takes in a parameter that is a data object:

```
addColor(_ coreDataManagerContext: NSManagedObjectContext, _ object: Color?) {//code here}
```

The issue is that it takes in an object: `Color?` that needs to be mocked.
Here is what the original `Color` model looks like, it's parsed in Swift 4 :

```
class Color: Codable {

    var id: String
    var name: String


    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "Id"
        case name = "Name"

    }
}
```

I thought about doing something like this:

```
class mockColorObject: Color {

   self.name = "red"//error here
}
```

but get the error: "expected declaration"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to set this variable in an initializer:

```
class mockColorObject: Color {

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        try super.init(from: decoder)
        self.name = "red"
    }
}
```

However, if you can change the code being tested, it might be a better strategy to define a `ColorType` protocol that `Color` and `mockColorObject` both conform to, since subclassing for the purpose of mocking can lead to problems.

Comment: If possible please provide eg using protocol, that will help me for better unit test case writting.